# Receive string via Bluetooth android (without line feed or Carriage Return)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

There are a lot of questions on stack overflow on how to receive data (string) from a Bluetooth device but I have never seen a question on how to receive data (string) without checking for LF or CR.

This code works perfectly when the device send a LF at the end of the String:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //ASCII code for Line Feed

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
        inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        inStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        //test
                                        textview1.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    workerThread.start();
```

But the device that sends the string does not send a Line feed neither a CR at the end. I have tried many things (also the Bluetooth guide from Google (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)). I want to receive all the data that is send to the app (and for testing display the received String in a textview).

Thanks in advance,
Michielvk

Comment: If it does not send CRLF what does it send ? Is it a null-terminated string ?

Comment: It sends a String but just don't add anything at the end. This is an example string: `10000000000000000000000000000000000000` but the string has value's in it instead of '0'. If the device sends 2 strings it would look like: `1000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: So the string is prefixed with a `1` ?

Comment: Yes the string I need to receive always starts with a 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Assuming all strings start with a "1" character, you should be able to read the **second to last** string by replacing `final byte delimiter = 10;` by `final byte delimiter = 49;` (since 49 is decimal representation of "1" in ASCII table).</s>

There's no way to read the last string (and assert you're reading the **full** string, not only a part) if there's no suffix delimiter.

### EDIT :

You gave the protocol's documentation in this comment feed. The doc says :
*The result string [...] consists of 38 ASCII characters.*

According to the fact that each response consists of 38 ASCII characters, you should be able to read all messages by replacing :
`if (b == delimiter) {`
with :
`if (readBufferPosition >= 37) {`

Comment: I just tested it and no luck, the app does not crash or anything but I don't receive anything either (I don't see text appearing in my textview). And if I delete the delimiter and just receive the full string?

Comment: This is the code  form the google guide `while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }` there is no delimiter either?

Comment: @Michielvk what is the name or ref. of the device you want to communicate with ?

Comment: @Michielvk To make sure we talk about the same thing : are you trying to read messages sent with the **Figure 15.2** protocol ?

Comment: @Michielvk I've edited my answer, let me know if it works.